# Python Selenium does not save values to db

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium to populate a huge translation form, so someone does not have to copy paste a few thousand lines from a CSV file. (The task needs to be done with selenium because the original programmer who has the source code is not available atm.)

The script works perfectly and populates all textareas with the required text. The last thing which must be done is click on save. The click works, but none of the values are saved to the db.

I used selenium earlier for such tasks and it always worked. Could it be an issue with **chrome using automated testing software**?

Populating the fields manually and click save does work and keep the values.

I have never encountered such behaviour with selenium, someone does have an idea?

I dont think its an issue with the code because there are no errors + I see that the fields are correctly populated, but here is how I populate the textarea fields:

```
for i in worksheet:
    if i[col_count].column == DATEI_UEBERSETZUNG_SPALTE:  
        if i[0].value != "Counter":
            try:     
                elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[.='%s']" % i[0].value)
                textarea_elem = elem.find_element_by_xpath('(..//textarea)[2]')
                if i[col_count].value:
                    textarea_elem.clear()     
                    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].value = arguments[1]', textarea_elem, i[col_count].value)
                else:
                    print (DATEI, i[0].value, "nicht übersetzt")    
            except Exception as e:
                print (DATEI, i[0].value, "Spalte konnte nicht auf der Webseite gefunden werden")
```

Loading selenium:

```
chromedriver = "drivers/chromedriver.exe"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
```

**The Issue:**

The textarea content is submitted by adding this content to an array `onKeyup`.
Which means I need to call an additional onKeyup after populating a textarea.

```
<textarea onkeyup="$(&quot;:ui-fancytree&quot;).fancytree(&quot;getNodeByKey&quot;, &quot;_3389&quot;).data.editedLang = this.value" style="width:100%;">top</textarea>
```

Here I need to call an onKeyup event so the content gets added:

```
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].value = arguments[1]', textarea_elem, i[col_count].value)
```

Comment: are you sure you're running selenium tests against the same server (configured with the same database) as you run it manually?

Comment: Yes I am sure its the correct server. I think there is a problem with the value of the textarea, I need to change the html/text. Currently working on that

Comment: Okay I found the issue, see my edit, needs probably a new question.

Comment: Is it not very strange to have this behavior on onKeyup instead of onChange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is pretty unique. To get the new value from the textarea an `onKeyup` event was required, which populated an array. The content of this array is used for submission.

I simply needed to add a random key event so the values which have been populated by selenium will be added to the arrays.

I added this key event after a textarea element was populated:

```
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].value = arguments[1]', textarea_elem, i[col_count].value)
textarea_elem.send_keys(Keys.DOWN)
```

Comment: Just excellent. You helped me to solve my issue!